# No such customer error in stripe

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, stripe-payments

I am using stripe component in my application,when I tested with sk_test_1XXXXXX all payments were success,now I changed that key to another sk_test_2XXX,when iam trying to pay through this,getting an error "No such custome -cus_xxxxxxxxxxx".How to resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created that customer with your 1st test key. These customers will be invisible (as well as any cards, subscriptions, etc) to your second test key.

Once you changed / moved key you'll need to recreate these test customers, they are not shared between test keys and accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Your customer does not exist. Try login into the stripe dashboard and seeing if that customer exists.